# Awesome does not create listing in gdm

Tags: gdm, awesome

I have installed awesome desktop from the terminal using `apt-get`.  But it does not create a listing in the gdm during login.  Is there any way to create a listing in gdm?
Also I am not able to edit the awesome.desktop file
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like this is a documented feature even though it is listed as a bug:

> **[Bug Description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1094811)**
>
> When installing awesome, it does not create an entry to launch the window manager from GDM or LightDM or KDM

[Hairong Zhu (hrzhu) wrote on 2013-04-26](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1094811/comments/8):

> The bug still exists in Xubuntu 13.04 release. And I can confirm that delete `NoDisplay=true` in `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop` solves the problem.

[James Crowther (j1aks) wrote on 2013-05-08](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1094811/comments/11):

> just tried this in Ubuntu 13.4 (x64) and I can confirm that just changing `NoDisplay=true` to   `NoDisplay=false` in `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop` is sufficient to make it show up in the window manager list on the login screen.

---

You can edit the file with `sudo gedit /usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop`.

Comment: I am not able to edit that file

Comment: Aha. explain why not? Mind you: of course you need admin thus 'sudo' permissions to be able to edit that file.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot I can't edit it even if I'm root

Comment: no I do not see that in the screenshot?! I would a suggest doing it from command line as usual with  `sudo gedit /usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop` Should work.